# Mysql output for first row works fine, for other rows doesn't

Tags: php, mysql

My forum has users which can refer other users. I store them in a table like

| UID | referrer | Referral |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 300 |  | 302,304 |
| 302 | 300 | 303 |
| 303 | 302 | 305,306,307 |
| 304 | 300 | 308 |
| 308 | 304 | 309 |

Now Level 0, there is UID 300
at level A, there is 302 and 304
at level B, there is 303 and 308
at level C, there is 305,306,307 and 308.

Now I am expecting below code to show as total number as 4, but it shows only 3. Which means it only counts first tree(only level c referrals under 302 and not 304). I want to make it to work, please help.

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT group_concat(uid) FROM mybb_users WHERE referrer='300'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $abc= $row['group_concat(*)'];   

    $sql = "SELECT uid FROM mybb_users WHERE referrer='$abc'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $wbc= $row["uid"];
       
       $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM mybb_users WHERE referrer='$wbc'";
       $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
       if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
         while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['count(*)'];          }
    } else {
       echo "0";  
      }
      }
    } else {
       echo "0";
    }
    
  }
  
} else {
  echo "0";
}

                    ?>
```

```
  $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM mybb_users WHERE referrer='$wbc'";
```

It should show total number as 4, not 3. But it's not working.

Comment: First off, you are storing delimited data in a relational database, this is a nope; if you normalised your table your queries become easier to write and performance won't suck.

Comment: @Stu, I think that just deleting column **Referral** would do the trick. It simply replicates information from the other 2 columns.

Comment: Hey @Stu, can you guide me where to start in going forward in the direction you're pointing at. I appreciate your time.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware If I delete Referral column, how would I know the parent referrer? Sorry to sound stupid.

Comment: No, it's not stupid. If you, for instance want to create the content of the **Referral** column, for user 300, you do: `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(referrer) FROM users WHERE UID = 300 GROUP BY referrer;`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I appreciate your response, but this query generates only Level A members. I want separately count Level C members...

Comment: I though to meant: _"If I delete column **Referral** how would I know what was in it?"_. That is the question I answered.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thanks Kiko! But my motive to ask the question was to count Level C members. Can you elaborate that, please.

Comment: I understood your question, but I don't like to answer it. If I did it would involve nasty nested queries, or something similar. Ugly. Normally I would do this using OOP, where all those things don't really get ugly. In other words: I'm not the guy to answer your question.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware It's alright KIKO! Thanks for the time, I appreciate your kind words and the knowledge your provided, thanks once again. God bless!